# Automatic exit from Bash shell script on error

Tags: bash, shell, error-handling, exit

I've been writing some shell script and I would find it useful if there was the ability to halt the execution of said shell script if any of the commands failed. See below for an example:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd some_dir

./configure --some-flags

make

make install
```

So in this case, if the script can't change to the indicated directory, then it would certainly not want to do a *./configure* afterwards if it fails.

Now I'm well aware that I could have an if check for each command (which I think is a hopeless solution), but is there a global setting to make the script exit if one of the commands fails?

Comment: answer goes to Adam for the detail regarding set -e (which is exactly wanted). Also thanks to a_m0d for the info on traps (though not 100% relevant).

Comment: Do these answers apply to `sh` just the same as `bash`?

Answer (score 1313, accepted):

Use the [`set -e`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Set-Builtin) builtin:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
# Any subsequent(*) commands which fail will cause the shell script to exit immediately
```

Alternatively, you can pass `-e` on the command line:

```
bash -e my_script.sh
```

You can also **disable** this behavior with `set +e`.

You may also want to employ all or some of the the `-e` `-u` `-x` and `-o pipefail` options like so:

```
set -euxo pipefail
```

`-e` exits on error, `-u` errors on undefined variables, `-x` prints commands before execution, and `-o (for option) pipefail` exits on command pipe failures. Some gotchas and workarounds are documented well [here](https://vaneyckt.io/posts/safer_bash_scripts_with_set_euxo_pipefail/).

(*) Note:

> The shell does *not* exit if the command that fails is part of the
> command list immediately following a **while** or **until** keyword,
> part of the test following the **if** or **elif** reserved words, part
> of any command executed in a **&&** or **||** list except the command
> following the final **&&** or **||**, any command in a pipeline but
> the last, or if the command's return value is being inverted with
> **!**

(from `man bash`)

Comment: Is this also a Bourne Shell builtin?

Comment: @Tom Yes: See  http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/set.html#tag_04_127_03

Comment: 'Set +e' will revert the setting again, so you can have only certain blocks that exit automatically on errors.

Comment: If shell script executes commands on a remote server will it also break if any of remote commands will produce an error or does `set -e` have also be included into remote commands sequence?

Comment: Also, issue `set -o pipefail` if you want to catch failed commands in pipes such as `command1 | command2` (where `command1` failed): *The exit status of a pipeline is the exit status of the last command in the pipeline, unless the pipefail option is enabled (see The Set Builtin). If pipefail is enabled, the pipeline’s return status is the value of the last (rightmost) command to exit with a non-zero status, or zero if all commands exit successfully.*

Comment: Is there a possibility to exit when a command in `$(...)` fails? If I use `set -e` and write `false`, the shell exits. But it does not exit on `echo $(false)`. Is there a way to *fix* this?

Comment: Does this print out the command line that failed if it failed?

Comment: @Jonny, if you use `set -o verbose` or `set -x` the commands issued will be "echoed" similar to DOS bat files without "echo off". Not only the last one, though.

Comment: Similarly, you can use `unset -e` to turn it off if the context you're running your script in has it enabled already.

Comment: Please be aware that `set -e` is a shaky feature that might sometimes just not do what you expect. See here for a wonderful explanation: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105

Comment: Does it work on the shebang line?

Comment: Great answer, would be nice to also add explanation for `-x` as you used it in your example.`-x  Print commands and their arguments as they are executed.` from [man page](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/seth.html)

Comment: `-x` enables a mode of the shell where all executed commands are printed to the terminal

Comment: `set` is documented on line 3229 in `man bash`, at least on Ubuntu.  You can search for it by typing `/` to search, and then entering `set [`  There are a mind boggling amount of options that are very useful for controlling how your shell, or scripts, run.

Answer (score 86):

To exit the script as soon as one of the commands failed, add this at the beginning:

```
set -e
```

This causes the script to exit immediately when some command that is not part of some test (like in a `if [ ... ]` condition or a `&&` construct) exits with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: More information here: http://www.davidpashley.com/articles/writing-robust-shell-scripts.html#id2382181

Answer (score 79):

Use it in conjunction with `pipefail`.

```
set -e
set -o pipefail
```

-e (errexit): Abort the script at the first error, when a command exits with non-zero status (except in *until* or *while* loops, *if-tests*, and list constructs)

-o pipefail: Causes a pipeline to return the exit status of the last command in the pipe that returned a non-zero return value.

[Chapter 33. Options](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/options.html)

Comment: That's "set -o errexit", or "set -e".

Comment: In case anyone's wondering, it works on Bourne Shell too (`/bin/sh`)

Answer (score 59):

Here is how to do it:

```
#!/bin/sh

abort()
{
    echo >&2 '
***************
*** ABORTED ***
***************
'
    echo "An error occurred. Exiting..." >&2
    exit 1
}

trap 'abort' 0

set -e

# Add your script below....
# If an error occurs, the abort() function will be called.
#----------------------------------------------------------
# ===> Your script goes here
# Done!
trap : 0

echo >&2 '
************
*** DONE *** 
************
'
```

Comment: trap 'abort' 0 <- why you are doing trap on "0" not "1"?

Comment: 0 -- `EXIT`, IOW trap on exit

Comment: If you do not use "exit" in a EXIT ('0') trap the shell will exit with the original exit value preserved!

Comment: Please expand this answer. How exactly does this technique work?

Answer (score 31):

An alternative to the accepted answer that fits in the first line:

```
#!/bin/bash -e

cd some_dir  

./configure --some-flags  

make  

make install
```

Comment: I've seen this before (putting '-e' in the #! line), but for me it does not work as expected with bash v3.2.57 on Mac OS X.  Simple test scripts that invoke /usr/bin/false followed by echo do not bail when expected.  Using "set -e" as accepted above works fine.

Answer (score 23):

One idiom is:

```
cd some_dir && ./configure --some-flags && make && make install
```

I realize that can get long, but for larger scripts you could break it into logical functions.

Comment: and you can add a newline after the `&&` for readability

Answer (score 19):

I think that what you are looking for is the `trap` command:

```
trap command signal [signal ...]
```

For more information, see [this page](http://www.davidpashley.com/articles/writing-robust-shell-scripts/#idm5150200).

Another option is to use the `set -e` command at the top of your script - it will make the script exit if any program / command returns a non true value.

Answer (score 14):

One point missed in the existing answers is show how to inherit the error traps. The `bash` shell provides one such option for that using `set`

> -E
>
> If set, any trap on `ERR` is inherited by shell functions, command substitutions, and commands executed in a subshell environment. The `ERR` trap is normally ***not*** inherited in such cases.

---

[Adam Rosenfield's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2871034/5291015) recommendation to use `set -e` is right in certain cases but it has its own potential pitfalls. See [GreyCat's BashFAQ - 105 - Why doesn't set -e (or set -o errexit, or trap ERR) do what I expected?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105)

According to the manual, set -e exits

> if a simple commandexits with a non-zero status. The shell does not exit if the command that fails is part of the command list immediately following a **`while`** or **`until`** keyword, part of the **`test in a if statement`**, part of an **`&&`** or **`||`** list except the command following the **`final && or ||`**, **`any command in a pipeline but the last`**, or if the command's return value is being inverted via **`!`**".

which means, `set -e` does not work under the following simple cases (detailed explanations can be found on the wiki)

1. Using the arithmetic operator `let` or `$((..))` ( `bash` 4.1 onwards) to increment a variable value as

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env bash
   set -e
   i=0
   let i++                   # or ((i++)) on bash 4.1 or later
   echo "i is $i"
   ```
2. If the offending command is *not* part of the last command executed via `&&` or `||`.  For e.g. the below trap wouldn't fire when its expected to

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env bash
   set -e
   test -d nosuchdir && echo no dir
   echo survived
   ```
3. When used incorrectly in an `if` statement as, the exit code of the `if` statement is the exit code of the last executed command. In the example below the last executed command was `echo` which wouldn't fire the trap, even though the `test -d` failed

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env bash
   set -e
   f() { if test -d nosuchdir; then echo no dir; fi; }
   f 
   echo survived
   ```
4. When used with command-substitution, they are ignored, unless `inherit_errexit` is set with `bash` 4.4

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env bash
   set -e
   foo=$(expr 1-1; true)
   echo survived
   ```
5. when you use commands that look like assignments but aren't, such as `export`, `declare`, `typeset` or `local`. Here the function call to `f` will *not* exit as `local` has swept the error code that was set previously.

   ```
   set -e
   f() { local var=$(somecommand that fails); }        
   g() { local var; var=$(somecommand that fails); }
   ```
6. When used in a pipeline, and the offending command is *not* part of the last command. For e.g. the below command would still go through. One options is to enable `pipefail` by returning the exit code of the *first* failed process:

   ```
   set -e
   somecommand that fails | cat -
   echo survived
   ```

The ideal recommendation is to *not* use `set -e` and implement an own version of error checking instead. More information on implementing custom error handling on one of my answers to [Raise error in a Bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50270940/5291015)

Comment: Really helpful. Thanks!