# Why doesn't `cat foo.txt | while read` fail if file not found?

Tags: bash

I use this loop to iterate through files or, if there are no files, read stdin:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
cat "$@" | while read arr ; do
    echo "Got this line ${arr}"
done
```

The problem is that if the file doesn't exist, it doesn't error out.

You can see the full example here:
https://github.com/StackExchange/blackbox/blob/master/tools/mk_rpm_fpmdir

`cat` does return error code 1 if any file is not found. However the error doesn't cause the program to stop.

How can I iterate through `$@` and fail if a file is not found?

Comment: Triple quotes don't mean anything to the shell so `"""$@"""` is just `"$@"` with extra empty strings on each side. Also this isn't "iterating" in any way. `cat` is just going to dump the contents from all the files in a continuous stream until it finishes. And the reason this isn't failing is because `set -e` only works on "simple commands". See http://stackoverflow.com/q/25794905/258523 .

Comment: It's the right-hand side of a pipeline -- not the left -- that determines the exit status of that pipeline as a whole, unless `shopt -s pipefail` is set.

Comment: The bash idiom `cat """$@"""` means "all the args, but quoted so that if they contain spaces it still works".

Comment: @TomOnTime, `cat "$@"` means the same thing. The extra quotes have no effect.

Comment: @lurker Yes, I see the error message. However, the script doesn't "exit 1" and therefore other automated processes don't see that the script had a problem.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Ok, I've removed the extra quotes but that's unrelated to the problem.

Comment: Do you want this to exit as soon as a file can't be found or just error at the end if any files couldn't be found?

Comment: Correction to the above comment: It's `set -o pipefail`, not `shopt -s pipefail`.

Comment: BTW, `read -a arr` and then dereferencing `"$arr"` will only give you the first element of the array, rather than its complete contents. You need to use `"${arr[@]}"` to get complete contents.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yeah, that "-a" is an artifact of the full code example that is linked to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several available options. One is to simply ditch `cat`, and thus have no pipeline (which has the advantageous side effect of avoiding subshell use, and thus allowing changes to shell state -- variables set, etc -- to last beyond the inner loop):

```
set -e
for f; do # in "$@" is implicit
  while read -r -a arr; do
    printf 'Got line: '
    printf '%q ' "${arr[@]}"
    printf '\n'
  done <"$f"
done
```

The above also goes out of its way to print the content read in a way that entirely preserves the array read, and prints its contents unambiguously (distinguishing an array containing two elements `foo` `bar baz` from one containing three elements `foo` `bar` `baz`).

---

Another is to set `pipefail`, which will cause a pipeline to be considered failed if any component of a pipeline returns a nonzero exit status, including `cat`:

```
set -e
set -o pipefail
cat "$@" | while IFS= read -r; do
  printf 'Got line: %q\n' "$REPLY"
done
```

This works by overriding the default behavior by which only the right-hand side of a pipeline matters for purposes of considering the overall exit status of the command.

Answer (score 1):

```
for f in "${@}"; do
    test -f "${f}" || exit # fail if file doesn't exist
    cat "${f}" | awk '{print "Got this line" $0}'
done
```

Comment: With `set -e` just `test -f "$f"` is enough for this to bail out actually. And you need to quote `"$@"` to be safe.

Comment: Still needs to be `test -f "$f"`, not `test -f $f`.

Comment: There's no correctness value to the extra curly braces here, btw. They're absolutely not a substitute for quotes.

Comment: fair enough. in principle it's fine though. I wouldn't used `set -e`. curly braces are good practice in general.

Comment: I personally disagree -- I find that excessive use hurts readability -- but that's bikeshedding, to be sure. I certainly can't argue that they're harmful in any correctness-impacting way.

Comment: my personal opinion is that it doesn't affect readability that badly. also I use an IDE that performs static analysis on the fly, which squiggles these when I don't do it. It is very easy for unintended consequences to take hold in shell-scripts, so it's good to use whatever protections you can.

Comment: robert, I'm just curious, which IDE are you using?

Comment: I probably can't name the IDEs, but the plugin is called BashSupport by Joachim Ansorg, and it's very good. The IDEs in question usually have a freely available "community edition" ;)