# Can I make bash report errors only errors at the end of a script?

Tags: bash, conditional-statements

I have a bash script which sequentially executes many tasks. 
However, because I do not want to see simple status messages (such as the long output of `yum -y update`), I ignored all those messages using:

```
#!/bin/bash
(
 yum -y update
 cd /foo/bar
 cp ~/bar /usr/bin/foo
 ...
 ...
) > /dev/null
```

This does the job just fine, but what if something went wrong, like `cp` failed to copy some file? If this happens, I would like to catch the error and exit immediately, before the process continues.

How can I exit the process and show the related error? Normally, 
an if/else clause would have to be used, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
yum -y update

if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "error "
    exit 1
fi
```

But the problem with this approach is that it would show the process; therefore, I would have to use `> /dev/null` on each line; more importantly, if I had more than 100 things to do, then the I would have to use many if/else statements.

Is there a convenient solution for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automatic exit from bash shell script on error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870992/automatic-exit-from-bash-shell-script-on-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than running your commands in `(...)` use `set -e` OR `bash -ec` to execute them:

```
bash -ec 'set -e
yum -y update
cd /foo/bar
...
...
cp ~/bar /usr/bin/foo' > /dev/null 2> errlog
```

OR using `set -e`:

```
(
set -e
yum -y update
cd /foo/bar
...
...
cp ~/bar /usr/bin/foo
) > /dev/null 2> errlog
```

**`-e` option will make sure to exit the sub shell as soon as an error occurs.**

Comment: But they way you are doing it would not be convenient to write 100 task in one line, and also how do i get the error when bash exist after it ?

Comment: No need to write them on line, let me edit to clarify.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, but can I still catch the error before/after the  `/dev/null` and show the error before it exists?

Comment: `> /dev/null` is only redirecting stdout so stderr is still available for you to grab.

Comment: Don't run with `bash -ec`. Instead, `set -e` inside your script.

Comment: But the question is, how would the error be caught and displayed at the end? I haven't dealt with `-ec` or `-e` flags before.

Comment: @Contax: the script will just stop, and you'll have the error messages the commands send to stderr on your terminal. Just try it with a dummy example.

Comment: Yes `set -e` will also exit the script immediately. You can redirect the stderr using `2>errfile`

Comment: @anubhava thanks. In the last line would changing this `2> errlog` to `echo 2>` work. I am clueless about this, I'have been using bash since a couple of hours.

Comment: `2> errlog` will redirect stderr to a file called `errlog` that you can examine/process as per your need like `cat errlog`

Comment: Ok, I didn't want to store the error, I just wanted it to get echo'ed as the script exists. But, I guess I could use cat for that.

Comment: If you remove `2> errlog` from above script it will automatically print stderr on your terminal, nothing special is needed for that.