# Fail Jenkins job when nosetests fail

Tags: python, shell, jenkins, continuous-integration

I am managing deployment / CI of a Flask app through Jenkins. I have a build step in the form of an executed shell which runs a shell script in the host that in turns runs nosetests.

The Jenkins shell command looks like so:

```
$WORKSPACE/ops/test_integration.sh
```

`integration.sh` looks like so:

```
SETTINGS_FILE="settings/integration.py" nosetests $@
```

How do I have the jenkins job fail and discontinue the build if the nosetests in the above shell script fail? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect nosetests will return a non zero value on failure

so you can set the shell to auto fail with

```
set -e
```

or any of the other options in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870992/automatic-exit-from-bash-shell-script-on-error)