# How to get Ruby script to fail when shelled-out command returns with non-zero exit code?

Tags: ruby, command-line-interface

In a Ruby script, there are [various ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232/calling-shell-commands-from-ruby/2400#2400) to call system commands / command lines

1. backticks: `` `command arg1 arg2` ``
2. delimited form, e.g. `%x(command arg1 arg2)` (other delimiters available)
3. `Kernel#system` method: `system('command arg1 arg2')`
4. `Kernel#exec` method: `exec('command arg1 arg2')`

If I want the Ruby script to fail (with an exception) when a called command fails (with a non-zero exit code) I can either check for the exit code in the special variable `$?` for the first two variants:

```
`command arg1 arg2`
fail unless $? == 0
```

or

```
%x,command arg1 arg2,
fail unless $? == 0
```

If I'm fine with the command's standard output going to the Ruby script's standard output (and I am), I can use variant 3 and check its return value:

```
unless system('command arg1 arg2')
  fail
end
```

If I don't care about the ability to rescue the exception nor about the stacktrace printing behavior of unrescued exceptions, I can of course use `exit(1)` or in the first two variants `exit($?)` in place of `fail`.

If further the execution of the command is the last thing the Ruby script should do, even when the command succeeds (exit code `0`), I can use the fourth variant:

```
exec('command arg1 arg2')
```

This will replace the Ruby process with the new process created by invoking the command, but the effect for the caller of the Ruby script will be the same: He sees a non-zero exit code exactly if the called command caused a non-zero exit code.

I very much like the conciseness of the fourth variant, but if executing the command isn't the last thing to do in case it succeeds, I can unfortunately not use it. The conditional `fail` or `exit` invocations of the other variants look very unclean in comparison and in one usecase of mine more often than not violate the single level of abstraction and single responsibility principles.

I could of course easily write a wrapper function for any of the first three approaches to make their usage look just as concise, but as this seems like such a fundamental modus operandi, **I wondered whether Ruby already has something like that built in** ... be it a utility function I could use instead of a wrapper of my own, or a mechanism that changes the behavior of one or several of the command invocation methods to cause an error or a non-zero exit when a command fails, analogous to [sh](/questions/tagged/sh)'s and [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)'s [option to `set -e`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2871034/674064).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know there is no built-in way to do this, but you can almost get the behavior you want with a little metaprogramming magic

```
def set_exit enable
  if enable
    define_method :system do |*args|
      Kernel.system *args
      exit $?.exitstatus unless $?.success?
    end
  else
    define_method :system, Kernel.instance_method(:system)
  end
end

set_exit true
# ...
# any failed system calls here will cause your script to exit
# ...
set_exit false
# now system is back to normal
```

This works by redefining `system` for `Object`, while explicitly using `Kernel.system` when the built-in behavior is needed.

Comment: Nice. Since [backquotes use `Kernel#\``](http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_expressions.html#UB), I guess this approach would work for them, too.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that was actually a method! Yeah, it appears to work just fine if you substitute `:\`` for `:system`