# UNIX Why does this command not exit my program?

Tags: unix

I am trying to get this program to exit if it cannot find the file that has to be deleted. Or if it won't delete for any reason.

When I use this it runs my program it gives me an error "cannot find file" and completes my program successfully.

```
del `unixpath2win filename` 
rc=$?  
if [ $rc -ne 0 ] ; then    
  echo_c $1 "error with deletion of filename"    
  checkrc.sh $rc    
  exit 1 
fi
```

Comment: You can usu set -e ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/2871034/280842

Comment: What is *del*? Shouldn't it be *rm*?