# Going inside if condition, even my return value is 0

Tags: shell, if-statement

```
sqlplus system/root @orcl<<END
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
VAR RET NUMBER
EXEC :RET := 1
EXEC :RET := ${CREATE_FUNCTION}('${WKDir}','${WKFile}', ${DAYS})
EXIT :RET
END
Rtn=$?
echo The value is $Rtn
    if[[ ${Rtn} != 0 ]] then
        echo "Error"
        exit 1
    fi
echo "RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR"

#########################################################################
# PL/SQL ｺ・・ﾂｹﾔ
#########################################################################
sqlplus system/root @orcl<<END
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
VAR RET NUMBER
EXEC :RET := 1
EXEC :RET := ${DELETE_FUNCTION}('${WKDir}','${WKFile}', ${COMMIT_CNT})
EXIT :RET
END
```

In the above code the value of `Rtn` is `0`. But it is getting inside the if condition and printing "Error". Where as I need to continue with the pl/Sql code.

Comment: According to the code `Rtn=$?`. Is `$?` zero?

Comment: Yes, The value of Rtn=0

Comment: This can't be the program you actually use, `if[[` is a syntax error.

Comment: IMO, the behaviour you describe can't occur. Run again your script with `-x` and show the output.

Answer (score 0):

Amend your script as below and it should work.

```
Rtn=$?
echo The value is $Rtn
    if [ ${Rtn} != 0 ]; then
        echo "Error"
        exit 1
    fi
echo "RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR"
```

Answer (score 0):

By default a shell script doesn't terminate on error, it just prints an error message to stderr and continues to execute subsequent commands. (This behaviour can be changed by [set -e](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2871034/8868289) at the beginning of your script).

In your case (as already mentioned in comments) `if[[` isn't correct syntax for `if` (the space is missing), the shell interprets it as a name of a command, there is no command with this name in your system, so the shell throws an error like that:

```
./test.sh: line 6: if[[ 0 != 0 ]]: command not found
```

...and continues to execute the next two commands:

```
echo "Error"
exit 1
```

Just for the sake of curiosity, you can create an executable file named `if[[` (it could be just an `echo hello world`) and place it somewhere in the PATH. Your script will execute it.