# Bash script with multiple papermill commands does not fail on notebook errors

Tags: python, bash, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, papermill

I have a `refresh_data.sh` file which contains multiple papermill commands, for example:

```
papermill notebook_1.ipynb output_1.ipynb -p start "2017-12-01" -p date "2017-12-31"
papermill notebook_2.ipynb output_2.ipynb -p start "2018-01-01" -p date "2018-01-31"
```

If I get an error while it is running the first notebook, the process continues executing the second one.

In other words, an error in one of the notebooks doesn't "break" the overall script.

As far as I remember with normal python scripts if there is an error in one of the commands within the bash script it breaks the execution of the entire script.

What is the standard behaviour of a bash script in this case? Can I change it so that it stops as soon as there is an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your bash script is configured with: `set -e` it will fail if a command errors out:

[Automatic exit from bash shell script on error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870992/automatic-exit-from-bash-shell-script-on-error)

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
# Any subsequent(*) commands which fail will cause the shell script to exit immediately
```

You can run papermill using:

`--log-output` to get more information about why your notebook fail.

```
papermill "${INPUT_NOTEBOOK_PATH}" "${OUTPUT_NOTEBOOK_PATH}" --log-output
```

To capture notebook execution result you can always capture the result of any previous command using `$?`:

```
  papermill "${INPUT_NOTEBOOK_PATH}" "${OUTPUT_NOTEBOOK_PATH}" --log-output
  notebook_result=$?
  if [[ ${notebook_result} -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "All good"
  else
    echo $notebook_result
  fi
```