# How to kill bash execution of multiple python scripts if previous one fails?

Tags: python, bash

I have a bash script that executes a number python scripts. Is there a way to prevent the execution of script_2.py if 1_script.py throws back an exception?

```py
#!/usr/bin/bash

python Desktop/code/1_script.py
python Desktop/code/2_script.py
python Desktop/code/3_script.py
```

Thanks very much!

Comment: `python Desktop/code/1_script.py && python Desktop/code/2_script.py ...`

Comment: or write `set -e` at the top of your script

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automatic exit from bash shell script on error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870992/automatic-exit-from-bash-shell-script-on-error)

Comment: The exception is not important; the fact that an uncaught exception is just one way to produce a non-zero exit status is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `&&` to only execute the next command if the previous one completed succesfully (0 exit code).

```sh
#!/usr/bin/bash

python Desktop/code/1_script.py && python Desktop/code/2_script.py && python Desktop/code/3_script.py
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the response, I have done a test for when one of the scripts throws an exception on execution with your solution. In this scenario my gitbash terminal just froze and the prompt didn't return. Should the bash script return an error message or what ought to happen if one of the python scripts doesn't run without exception?

Answer (score -2):

DO step by step 
      At first execute `1_script.py`
then, execute another python files.

OR

```sh
python Desktop/code/1_script.py && python Desktop/code/2_script.py && python Desktop/code/3_script.py
```

OR

```
write set -e at the top of your script
```

"Thanks"