# Pressing no or cancel on zenity dialog exits script

Tags: bash, zenity

I am writing a script that opens a bunch of programs. However, sometimes I only want some of the programs open, so I am using zenity question dialogs to ask whether it should open each program.

```sh
    zenity --question --text "Start Firefox?"
    start_firefox=$?
    if [[ $start_firefox -eq 1 ]]; then
        # opens Firefox...
    fi
    zenity --question --text "Open Dolphin?"
    open_dolphin=$?
    if [[ $open_dolphin -eq 0 ]]; then
        directory=$(zenity --file-selection --directory)
        # continues to open Dolphin...
    fi
    zenity --question --text "Open gedit?"
    open_gedit=$?
    if [[ $open_gedit -eq 0 ]]; then
        # opens gedit...
    fi
```

The problem here is if I click on No on any of the questions, or Cancel on the file selector, it exits the entire script and I can't even collect the return value of the zenity dialog. The same code works just fine if I type it in a bash shell.

Answer (score 0):

I had to type the command `set +e` before I opened any zenity dialog boxes. This is because a bash script exits when a command returns a non-zero exit code, which it sees as failed. A zenity question returns 0 if the user clicked yes and 1 if the user clicked no. Since 1 is a non-zero exit code, bash thought the command failed, and terminated the entire script.

What the command above does is *don't stop the script on any non-zero exit status*, which has the side effect that other commands that fail won't exit the script either, so use with care.

Also see the question [Automatic exit from bash shell script on error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2870992/12452330).

Comment: "*`The default behavior of bash is set -e`*". I don't think so. Do you have any sources that state `set -e` is the default?

Comment: @Socowi Since the bash infopage didn't say anything about this, I looked that the bash [sources](https://github.com/bminor/bash/search?q=errexit_flag&unscoped_q=errexit_flag) and in fact, I discovered that this is *not* the default.

Comment: @Zenul_Abidin : You can see which options are in effect, by doing a `echo $-`. Unless you have set `-e` explicitly (for instance in your .bashrc), `e` won't be in the list.