# why bash does not exit on test syntax error?

Tags: bash, testing, syntax, exit

I would like a script to exit on a syntax error occurring on a test, but no luck :

```
bash -n "$0" || exit  # check script syntax

#set -xv
set -o nounset
set -o errexit
set -o pipefail # make pipes fail if one of the piped commands fails

if (( != 0 )); then  # syntax error here
  echo "after if"
fi

echo "should not reach this point, but indeed does"
```

output is :

```
./testscript: line 8: ((: != 0 : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "!= 0 ")
should not reach this point, but indeed does
```

any solution ?
thanks

Comment: The manual clearly explains this. *The shell does not exit if the command that fails is part of the command list immediately following a while or until keyword, **part of the test following the if or elif reserved words**, part of any command executed in a && or || list except the command following the final && or ||, any command in a pipeline but the last, or if the command's return value is being inverted with !.*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Automatic exit from bash shell script on error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870992/automatic-exit-from-bash-shell-script-on-error)

Comment: Yet another reason not to rely on `set -e`.

Comment: @oguzismail That manual quote refers to non-zero exit status, though, not syntax errors.

Comment: @BenjaminW. The syntax error still manifests as a non-zero exit code for the `((...))` command.

Comment: The error trap only triggers when your shell is *exiting* due to an error; it's not an exception handler.

Comment: From another perspective, a syntax error is not something that should happen at run-time, *period*. It's a bug to fix, not a condition to handle.

Comment: Adding an error trap handler does not help.

Comment: There's no good way to do this, but `shellcheck "$0" || exit` would work like a stricter version of your existing `bash -n` check