# How to fail the script on syntax error in bash

Tags: bash

I have following bash script and it appears in line `if [ $PYTHON3 = "true"]; then`, there must be a space after `"true"`. for if condition to work. When running however, it warns about a missing `]` but the script does not fail there. Is there a option I can enable to get script to fail on these type of issues?

```bash
#!/bin/bash

set -euxo pipefail

PYTHON3=true

pkgs=()

if [ $PYTHON3 = "true"]; then
    pkgs+=("python3")
fi

echo ">>>>>>"
echo "${pkgs[@]}"
```

I get following log when executed

```
:!bash ./test.sh

+ PYTHON3=true
+ pkgs=()
+ '[' true = 'true]'
./test.sh: line 9: [: missing `]'
+ echo '>>>>>>'
+ echo
>>>>>>
```

Comment: It's _not_ a bash syntax error. `[` is a separate command, not bash syntax; and because the way commands are wired to the shell only provides a single "exit status" signal with no distinction between programmer error and a false result, the shell has no way of knowing that it was a syntax problem in fact.

Comment: The right answer here is static checking. [`shellcheck`](https://www.shellcheck.net/) will detect this and many other errors, and doesn't have [the serious portability and reliability problems](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) caused by `set -e`.

Comment: (...and yes, I'm _extremely_ serious about the `set -euo pipefail` idiom being an antipattern; doing without `set -e` means writing explicit error checking and validating that error handling during code review, but that's _much_ better than having unpredictable runtime behavior).

Comment: That said, if you want an equivalent to `[` that _is_ bash syntax, you should be using `[[`.

Comment: This was also previously asked as [Why does bash not exit on test syntax error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60931316/why-bash-does-not-exit-on-test-syntax-error) (albeit titled somewhat inaccurately, insofar as in that case they're running a test that _isn't_ handled by `test`/`[`)

Comment: (yes, `[` is a builtin, but it's not a _special_ built-in; non-special builtins follow the normal rules -- which is to say, their behavior for most purposes is identical to how they'd operate if they were actually implemented by an external executable; since there _actually is_ a `/bin/[` or `/usr/bin/[` executable with standardized behavior, having a shell's built-in version of `[` differ would be a standards-compliance issue).

Answer (score 0):

The script didn't fail because `[ $PYTHON3 = "true"]` is a valid bash statement (meaning no syntax error).

`[` is a builtin command which returned `code 2` in this particular situation where it didn't find the closing `]`.

As `[ ...` is the condition of `if`, the script didn't stop.

Comment: The OP isn't asking why it happens; they're asking how to avoid it. (An answer that distinguished between `$?` being 1 vs 2 would make sense, then; alternately, on the linked duplicate, I have a community-wiki answer that suggests `[[`).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy The OP isn't asking why it happens `because` they have incorrect understanding of the situation. I don't think an answer that distinguished between $? being 1 vs 2 would make sense.

Comment: An answer that tested `$?` would _answer the literal question that was asked_; this doesn't.

Comment: I've edited the answer on the linked duplicate to include such an example, showing how to wrap `[` in such a way as to add exit-on-misuse functionality.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Why would you answer an literal question that is based on incorrect understanding of the situation ?

Comment: Because we're here _to help people learn how to better go about the practice of software development_. Filling gaps in theory is important and valuable, but the focus is on practice; one can _and should_ do both.

Comment: Agreed. Only in this circumstance, understanding is much more important than practice.